# How can my water cool down more quickly?

Tags: thermodynamics, heat, water

I have a cup and I can only pour hot water inside, I wanna know whether the heat will dissipate more quickly with more water or less water?
How about the occasion when my cup is well covered?

Answer (score 4):

The amount of [thermal energy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_energy) in the water is proportional to the volume of water (which is proportional to its size cubed: $r^3$).  The rate at which [heat can be dissipated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conduction_%28heat%29) (the rate it cools) is proportional to the surface area of the water (which is proportional to its size squared: $r^2$).  Thus, **the more water you have, the lower the ratio of surface-area to volume ($A / V \propto r^2 / r^3 = 1/r )$, and the longer it will take to cool**.

*Aside: this is why larger mammals have more trouble cooling themselves than smaller animals.  This is why [elephants have giant ears](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elephant#Ears): they drastically increase the surface area<sup>1</sup> to increase the rate of heat dissipation.*

If you cover the cup, it increases its [insulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_insulation) --- which is its resistance to exchanging heat with the environment.  More insulation means slower heat transfer, and in this case, slower cooling.

---

1: The ears also have excellent blood-flow, which keeps transferring heat from the body to the ears---just like the radiator in a car.

Answer (score 2):

You could also put black food-coloring in the hot water to make it radiate faster, because of course black bodies radiate faster. It's the same reason black coffee cools down faster than coffee which has added milk.

Comment: That's not how it works

Comment: Uh, yes it is...

Comment: A '*black*' body, does not refer to its color *per se*, but its spectrum.  For example, the sun (clearly not black) is very close to a black-body.  See, e.g., [this link](https://www.cfa.harvard.edu/~jbattat/a35/blackbody_color.html)

Comment: It is probably even the opposite, black objects tend to 'absorb' more light thus heat up a little bit (think about your black bicycle seat that heats up like crazy in the summer)

Comment: @zhermes you are wrong. The sun gives off light because it is hot, and therefore giving off lots of thermal radiation. But if you could have a ball of hydrogen that big at room temperature, it would indeed appear black. Putting black food colouring in water definitely would increase its rate of heat loss due to radiation. (Unless you left out in the sun of course.) But since a cup of water loses most of its heat due to convection, I doubt it would produce an easily measurable effect.

Comment: @zhermes or to put it another way, you're right in that the "black" in "black body" usually refers mostly to the spectral properties in the infra-red range - but most pigments that are black in the visual range are also black in the IR, so in practice painting things black does increase their rate of thermal radiation emission or absorption.

Comment: I am sorry, but I think black color absorb the heat, so my understanding in the occasion of cup and water, if the cup is black, then the liquid tends to cool down faster, while if the liquid is black(black coffee for instance), it takes more time to cool down than with milk added.  p.S.. I am really really an idiot in physics, and thank you guys for all the eyes-opening information!

Comment: or like why white people's eyes are lighter is because when we are over snow mountain, the black eyeballs will absorb more heat and then burn off the eyes. so I think black body absorbs instead of radiating heat?

Comment: I've started a [new thread](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/56887/does-an-objects-color-change-its-rate-of-cooling) on this subject - lets continue the discussion there.  I'm still entirely unconvinced.

Answer (score 1):

The question could perhaps benefit from some clarification.  The more water that is in the cup, the larger the surface that will be transferring heat from the water to the cup and to the surroundings, and more heat will be dissipated to the surroundings.

Covering the cup will do two things: 1) the most important is that it will reduce the heat loss due to evaporation, as the steam will condense inside the cup keeping its heat there rather than letting escape, 2) reduce heat loss due to radiation and convection by insulation.

A more interesting question might be whether the temperature of the water drops more quickly in the larger or smaller volume.  This question is answered above in the comparison of surface area and volume.